# Is there an plugin for Safari that opens certain file extensions?

Tags: safari, ms-office, safari-extensions, file-extensions

I have searched for quite awhile and I can't find anything that sounds similar to what I'm looking for.

A lot of my files that I access from my schools website have Microsoft Office extensions like .ppt, .doc, .docx, and so on.

Every time I open our "dailyschedule.doc" it opens a new Safari tab.. then downloads the doc file. I seriously have probably 30+ copies of these stupid things! Why can't they just be opened like a web page?

It's annoying and even Google search results will just download powerpoint files and open them up in ppt/keynote. PDF does it sometimes too, but it's so annoying!

Is there something that will let me just look at the files in safari without having to download them every single time I want to look at them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari downloads every file that it is not able to read (which is pretty much anything but website-formats such as html, css, xml)
There are some plugins that open special formats.
The first result from google is this one
http://www.schubert-it.com/free/

Answer (score 2):

The Web is the world of Safari. Proprietary file formats are what cause you pain. These usually don’t fit well with the Web.

[The *Word Browser Plugin*](http://www.schubert-it.com/free/) reads Word docs in Safari. I have not tried it, but you can trust it, its author Manfred Schubert usually does great work.

You may also like [*view.samurajdata.se*](http://view.samurajdata.se). It is a nice address for reading a document quickly **on the Web**.